# Accessing object property in Firebase Realtime Database ruleset

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I store data about trips in a Firebase Realtime Database. I have defined some user groups. I want only users from group "vips" to read trips that have freePlaces == 0 and all the others to read the remaining trips.

I tried to set such access rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "trips":{
          "$trip":{
            ".read": "root.child('users').child('vips').child(auth.uid).exists() || $trip.child('freePlaces') > 0"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

but Firebase tells me $trip has no method/property 'child'.

I tried to do it in a different way

```
{
  "rules": {
      "trips":{
          "$trip":{
            ".read": "root.child('users').child('vips').child(auth.uid).exists() || root.child('trips').child($trip).child('freePlaces') > 0"
           }
       }
   }
}
```

but Firebase says Invalid > expression: left operand must be a number or string.

What went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend playing close attention to the type of each expression in your rules:

- `$trip` is a [string](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#string_properties), which explains why you can't call `.child` on it. If you want to get a child of the node, you can just do: `data.child('freePlaces')`.
- `root.child('trips').child($trip).child('freePlaces')` is a location in the database, which [can't be compared with `>`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#_greater_than). If you want the value of the node, use `.val()`.

So combining these, your first snippet should be:

```
data.child('freePlaces').val() > 0
```